# Why is the ag-grid checkbox behaving like this

Tags: angular, checkbox, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid checkbox selection with angular 6 to show some data in the popup.So it makes sense that the row gets selected on clicking the checkbox .However in my case , simply clicking on a column value is also causing the checkbox to be selected .The following is a screenshot of my problem.[Image of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f8ZR.png)

The html code that i am using for my ag-grid is given below

```
<ag-grid-angular
    style="width:400px;height:274px" 
    class="ag-theme-blue"
    [rowData]="obj"
    [columnDefs]="ColumnDefs"
    [enableSorting]="true"
    [enableFilter]="true"
    [rowSelection]="row"
    (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"

    [rowMultiSelectWithClick]="true"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"


    [enableColResize]="true"


    >

    </ag-grid-angular>
```

my grid definition is give below , which i have initialized in ngOnInit function.

```
this.ColumnDefs=[ {"checkboxSelection":true,"headerName":"Intf","field":"outboundName",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:90,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"}},
{"headerName":"Comp","field":"success_no",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:75,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"}},
{"headerName":"Fail","field":"fail_no",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:75,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"}},
{"headerName":"Exec","field":"running_no",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:75,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"}},

{"headerName":"Total","field":"total",sortingOrder: ['asc','desc', 'null'],width:75,cellStyle:{'text-align': "left"}}]
```

So please help me in understanding what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
[suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
```

to your grid options

You can read more about it [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/)